# unable to prepare context: path "./mile-restoraunt-app" not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a local network for two services with a docker compose file.
service mysqldb - the data base for the spring boot app.
service app - the spring boot app.

this is the error i am receiving:
[image: running the docker compose command]

**these are my files**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-8
WORKDIR /mile-restoraunt-app
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./mile-restoraunt-app
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?useSSL=false",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db:
```

**.env file**

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=thanatos
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=restaurant
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3307
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306
SPRING_LOCAL_PORT=6868
SPRING_DOCKER_PORT=8080
```

And this is my directory
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `docker-compose.yaml` for a `app` you specified `build: ./mile-restoraunt-app`, but you run your command inside the `mile-restoraunt-app` folder. You need to change the build folder.

Comment: Sorry, i dont follow you. Can u give me an example of what u mean?

Comment: review your `docker-compose.yaml` file. Especially configuration for `app`. You specified `build` folder as `./mile-restoraunt-app`, but your `docker-compose.yaml` is located inside `mile-restoraunt-app`. That's why you see the exception `unable to prepare context`. You need to specify `./` instead

Comment: Thank you!!! That solved my problem. :)